# Why does my function not print every car number, just the first one

Tags: python

I have a task from school that gives me a license plate number from a witness were some numbers or letters are replaced with "?" since the witness is not sure about that letter or number. My job is to see which one of the car numbers also given might match with 'VF???55'. The problem is that it will only print the first license plate number that might match and not the next two. I know my code works if i drop the function part of it, but the task require me to make it a function.

Correct answer is: VF12355 VF77455 VF10055

```
car_numbers = ['VX33322','VF12355','VF77455','DA?????','VF10055']
def match_list(car_numbers):
    car = 'VF???55'
    for i in range(len(car_numbers)):
        if set(car) - set(car_numbers[i]) == {'?'}:
            return car_numbers[i]
    
print(match_list(car_numbers))
```

Comment: How can the loop continue after you've returned?

Comment: If you need to return a list, then you had better construct a list in your function, don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

To answer your specific question, it only returns one item because a function call can only return a single "thing" (object).

Once a function returns, it's "unwound from the stack" (effectively forgotten) and no more code will execute.

To get multiple values back from a function, you need to make the thing it returns an object with multiple values (a list).

That means you need to do all your processing before you do the return.

Try something like this

```
def match_list(car_numbers):
    car = 'VF???55'
    return [number for number in car_numbers if set(car) - set(number) == {'?'}]
```

It returns the entire list of matching numbers using a *list comprehension*.

To explain...

```
[<thing to return> for <name for each item> in <list of items> if <condition>]
```

In this case, we want to return the whole number, so it's `[number for number in ...]`

[Live Example](https://www.online-python.com/2C3a79lIJj)

Answer (score -1):

I created a new list to store the matches. Also take note of where I put my return statement so we can get all matches, store in the result list and then return the list. You can try this, it works:

```
car_numbers = ['VX33322','VF12355','VF77455','DA?????','VF10055']
res_list = []
def match_list(car_numbers):
    car = 'VF???55'
    for i in car_numbers:
        if set(car) - set(i) == {'?'}:
            res_list.append(i)  
    return res_list
    
print(match_list(car_numbers))
```

Output: `['VF12355', 'VF77455', 'VF10055']`.

Answer (score -2):

this method without indexing (and creating a new list of cars) works:

```py
car_numbers = ['VX33322','VF12355','VF77455','DA?????','VF10055']
def match_list(car_numbers):
    car = 'VF???55'

    found_car = []
    for car_number in car_numbers:
        if (set(car) - set(car_number)) == {'?'}:
            found_car.append(car_number)
    return found_car

    
print(match_list(car_numbers))
```

returns

```
['VF12355', 'VF77455', 'VF10055']
```

Comment: interestingly this question (along with all the others) gets a negative vote even though it provides a workable answer.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a searchable reference library, not to operate a help desk. *Logic* errors like in the OP almost always boil down to either something idiosyncratic that could never be made searchable (others are unlikely to have the same problem, and if they did, would have no idea what to search for), or are else (as in this case) duplicates of a common problem with an existing high-quality explanation. Such questions should be closed rather than answered; answering them interferes with site curation.

Comment: (Aside from that, on questions where an answer is merited, please actually *explain what is wrong* when answering a debugging question, rather than simply posting a fixed version.)